# Undefined Method when .build new Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and currently trying to make a little test website for me.I've got an issue in my code that states an "undefined method `service_providers' for #"
The line of code which produces the error is the following:

```
def new
    @service_provider = current_user.service_providers.build(serviceprovider_params)
end
```

My Database Model is Table "User" has_one "ServiceProvider" has_many "Services".
I use the rubygem "devise" for the user-model.
I've tried to transfer the idea of the micropost of the "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts) in my example app. In Listing 13.36 there's also this code because with this ruby knows the reference between the current_user and the micrrpost.
I don't have an idea why it isn't working with my code:

Model

```
class ServiceProvider < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :service

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :street, presence: true
  validates :plz, presence: true
  validates :location, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

end
```

Controller

```
class ServiceProvidersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_serviceprovider, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @service_provider = current_user.service_providers.build(serviceprovider_params)
  end

  def create
    @service_provider = current_user.service_provider.build(serviceprovider_params)
    if @service_provider.save
      redirect_to @service_provider, notice: "Gespeichert"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

    private
    def set_serviceprovider
      @service_provider = Service_Provider.find(params [:id])
    end

    def serviceprovider_params
      params.require(:service_provider).permit(:name, :street, :plz, :location)
    end
end
```

ServiceProvider-Helper

```
module ServiceProvidersHelper
  def current_service_provider
    @current_service_provider = service_provider.user_id.find(current_user.id)
  end
end
```

If there's some coding missing which you need for your help, please ask. I'm a newbie in coding with ruby, but i think taht must be the relevant parts of the code which is involved.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `has_one` association then you need to use `build_ASSOCIATION_NAME` so in this case, it will be `build_service_provider`

```
@service_provider = current_user.build_service_provider(serviceprovider_params)
```

Also, I think you need to take a look at this association

```
class ServiceProvider < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :service
```

If you are building an association with `has_many` then the class name should be plural.

Change it to

```
has_many :services
```